# text not aligned with corresponding checkbox

Tags: html, css, angularjs

```
<div ng-repeat="option in LgODDL track by $index">
    <label> 
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected[$index]" ng-click="toggleOrderSelection(option.Number, option.NumberDetails)">  {{option.NumberDetails}}
    </label>
</div>
```

I think this is my only css that could be affecting this:

```
input {
    line-height: normal;
    height: 22px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why the above code generates text not evenly aligned with the checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following styling to your `<input>` tag:

```
.checkbox-align {
  padding-top: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```